# Python Loop at scheduled hours

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I need to iterate some functions in Python every 5th minute of the day (`09:00:00`; `09:05:00`; `09:10:00`; ...). I guess that if I use the `sleep` function I would accumulate all the calculations time, slowly moving away from the 5th minute in execution. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: Look at the sched module?  https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use `crontab` in **Linux** to run a python script printing the time stamp every 5th minute. The following code is an example of using crontab

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python your_python_script.py
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could always check current time before scheduling another call and set the delay:

```
delay = (5 * 60 * 1000) - time_since_last_function_call
```

which will always result into something under 5 minutes. In python there's also [sched module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sched.html) with similar functionality.

Alternative and probably better solution would be to use [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

```
*/5 9 * * * /bin/python /your/script/path.py
```